# How to create a array of record values

Tags: functional-programming, f#

I have a problem, where I have a record (called Probablities in my case) that only consists of a certain type, and I want to create array with the record values.

```
type Probability = Probability of float 

type Probabilities = {
    Pp: Probability;
    Pf: Probability;
    Pd: Probability;
    Pg: Probability; 
 }
let calculatingSum (probablities : Probabilities) =
   probablities
   // I need something, that can transform probablities to an array of Probability
   // such that I can do something like
   [|1.0;0.5|]
   |> Array.sum
```

I know it is possible to access all the elements individually, but I really wanna avoid that.

Comment: If you have to fight the type system (otherwise you'd just restructure the record and sum fields' values explicitly) then it's high time to rethink either type design (or even the language choice :)). Do you really need a record if (at least sometimes) all you need is just a list of probabilities?

Comment: ("destructure" obviously, not "restructure" - noticed too late to fix)

Comment: I reconsidering my choice of type indeed, but I would like to know if it is possible :) - The reason why records are tempting is, that I can label my probabilities and I rarely need the list, but when validating it would make the code much more condense. Worse case, I can access them individually.

Comment: You could define a static member for `Probabilities` type (say, `AsList` that would return a list of probabilities) - not sure this is any better than explicit destructuring, but maybe less verbose. Another thing that comes to mind is reflection (https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/main/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/reflect.fsi#L327), but looks like quite a dirty hack that should be avoided whenever it is possible...

Comment: Could you elaborate on the reason why you'd like to avoid destructuring, like @KonstantinStrukov suggests?

Comment: The reason why i would like to avoid destructuring is, that as I understand it, I need to access each element of my record explicitly. This is a problem as I most likely would like to increase the number of element of my record. And I wanted the functionality to carry over, even though I added new elements. The suggestions below seems reasonable though, as I only need to do it once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had reason to treat the data both as a record and as a collection, I would make a conversion to a map (and transform that to array or list when needed)
Like so:

```
module Probabilities =
    let asMap (p : Probabilities) = 
        Map.ofList [
            "Pp", p.Pp
            "Pf", p.Pf
            "Pd", p.Pd
            "Pg", p.Pg
        ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could add a method to your `Probabilities` type that converts its contents into an array:

```ml
type Probabilities = {
    Pp: Probability;
    Pf: Probability;
    Pd: Probability;
    Pg: Probability; 
 }
with
    member this.ToArray =
        [|
            this.Pp
            this.Pf
            this.Pd
            this.Pg
        |]
```

And then use it like this:

```ml
let calculatingSum (probablities : Probabilities) =
   probablities.ToArray
        |> Array.sumBy (fun (Probability p) -> p)
        |> Probability
```